# How to parse the OpenAIStream so there are no spaces and lists are correctly formatted?

Tags: streaming, openai-api, chatgpt-api

[image]I have the OpenAI's API set to stream the response and it's working! The problem is the results have extra spaces and my formatting is not working to eliminate the spacing issue nor is it parsing the lists.  Here's the code.  How to correctly parse these 'chunks' after they are all received?

Messages Component of this React app:

```js
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (!inputText) return;

    const userMessage = {
        author: {
            id: user.id,
            username: user.username
        },
        text: `${selectedOption} ${inputText}`,
    };

    setMessages((prevMessages) => [...prevMessages, userMessage]);
    scrollToBottom();
    localStorage.setItem("messages", JSON.stringify(messages));

    let messageChunks = [];
    const systemMessage = {
        author: {
            id: 'system',
            username: 'System'
        },
        text: '',
    };

    setMessages((prevMessages) => [...prevMessages, systemMessage]);

    generateText({
            username: `Name: ` + user.username,
            inputText: `${selectedOption} ${inputText}`,
        },
        setShowModal,
        (chunk, isInitialChunk, isFinalChunk) => {
            messageChunks.push(chunk.trim());

            // Update the last system message with the new chunk
            setMessages((prevMessages) => {
                const lastSystemMessageIndex = prevMessages.length - 1;
                const updatedSystemMessage = {
                    ...prevMessages[lastSystemMessageIndex],
                    text: prevMessages[lastSystemMessageIndex].text + ' ' + chunk.trim(),
                };

                return [
                    ...prevMessages.slice(0, lastSystemMessageIndex),
                    updatedSystemMessage,
                    ...prevMessages.slice(lastSystemMessageIndex + 1),
                ];
            });

            if (isFinalChunk) {
                const formattedMessage = formatText(messageChunks.join(' ').replace(/\s+/g, ' '));
                console.log("Formatted text: ", formattedMessage);
                setMessages((prevMessages) => {
                    const lastSystemMessageIndex = prevMessages.length - 1;
                    const updatedSystemMessage = {
                        ...prevMessages[lastSystemMessageIndex],
                        text: formattedMessage || prevMessages[lastSystemMessageIndex].text, // Use formattedMessage if it's defined, otherwise use the original text
                    };

                    const updatedMessages = [
                        ...prevMessages.slice(0, lastSystemMessageIndex),
                        updatedSystemMessage,
                        ...prevMessages.slice(lastSystemMessageIndex + 1),
                    ];

                    return updatedMessages;

                });
            }
        },
        true,
        true,
        true,
        false,
        false
    );

    setInputText("");
};
const formatText = (text) => {
    let formattedText = text
        .replace(/\s+/g, ' ')
        .replace(/\s+([.,!?:;])/g, '$1')
        .replace(/([.,!?:;])\s+/g, '$1 ');

    const numberedListRegex = /(?:\s|^)(\d+)\.\s+([^\d\s][^\n]*)(?:\n|$)/gm;
    let match;
    const listItems = [];
    let lastIndex = 0;

    while ((match = numberedListRegex.exec(formattedText)) !== null) {
        if (match.index !== lastIndex) {
            const textBetweenMatches = formattedText
                .slice(lastIndex, match.index)
                .replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ')
                .trim();
            if (textBetweenMatches) {
                listItems.push(textBetweenMatches);
            }
            lastIndex = numberedListRegex.lastIndex;
        }
        // Add match[1] before match[2] to include the number in the list item
        listItems.push(`<li>${match[1]}. ${match[2].trim().replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ')}</li>`);
    }

    if (lastIndex !== formattedText.length) {
        listItems.push(formattedText.slice(lastIndex).replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ').trim());
    }

    if (listItems.length > 1) {
        formattedText = `<ol>${listItems.join('')}</ol>`;
    }
    formattedText = he.decode(formattedText);
    return formattedText;
};

///  OpenAIStream: 
const stream = new ReadableStream({
    async start(controller) {
        // callback
        function onParse(event: ParsedEvent | ReconnectInterval) {
            if (event.type === "event") {
                const data = event.data;

                if (data === "[DONE]") {
                    controller.close();
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    const json = JSON.parse(data);
                    const text = (json.choices[0].delta?.content || ""); // Remove newline



                    if (counter < 2 && text.includes("\n")) {
                        return;
                    }

                    const queue = encoder.encode(text);
                    controller.enqueue(queue);
                    counter++;
                } catch (e) {
                    // maybe parse error
                    controller.error(e);
                }
            }
        }

        const parser = createParser(onParse);

        const reader = res.body.getReader();

        while (true) {
            const {
                value,
                done
            } = await reader.read();
            if (done) break;
            parser.feed(decoder.decode(value));
        }
    },
});

return stream;
}
//// openai's aPI call: 
const generateText = async (
            params,
            setShowModal,
            onUpdate,
            isSystemMessage = false,
            useSecret = false,
            includeRecentMessages = false,
            waitForCompletion = false,
            skipModeration = false
        ) => {
            console.log("variables passed:", params);

            try {
                const isFlagged = skipModeration ? false : await moderateText(params, setShowModal);

                if (!isFlagged) {
                    const content = Object.values(params).join(" ");

                    const messages = [{
                        role: "user",
                        content: content
                    }, ];

                    if (isSystemMessage) {
                        const secret = useSecret ? process.env.REACT_APP_SECRET : "";
                        messages.unshift({
                            role: "system",
                            content: "generate content for audience of 6-17 year olds, do not refer to ages or young " + secret
                        });
                    }
                    if (includeRecentMessages && params.recentMessages && params.recentMessages.length > 0) {
                        prompt += "\n\nPrevious Messages:\n";
                        prompt += params.recentMessages.map(({
                            author,
                            text
                        }) => `${author.username}: ${text}`).join("\n");
                        prompt += "\n";
                    }

                    const payload = {
                        model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
                        messages: messages,
                        user: params.username,
                        temperature: 0,
                        max_tokens: 2000,
                    };
                    console.log(payload)
                    if (waitForCompletion) {
                        const response = await openai.post("/chat/completions", payload);
                        console.log(response.data.choices[0].message.content)
                        return response.data.choices[0].message.content;
                    } else {
                        const streamPayload = {
                            ...payload,
                            stream: true
                        };
                        const stream = await OpenAIStream(streamPayload, apiKey);
                        const reader = stream.getReader();
                        const decoder = new TextDecoder();

                        let isFirstChunk = true;
                        while (true) {
                            const {
                                value,
                                done
                            } = await reader.read();
                            if (done) break;
                            const text = decoder.decode(value);
                            onUpdate(text.trim(), isFirstChunk, false);
                            isFirstChunk = false;
                        }
                        onUpdate("", false, true);
                    }
```